# AutoHotkey doesn't work on the new Skype desktop version windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, skype

I have a script to be able to do Spanish/latin accents, the script works pretty much with all applications, but with the new Skype desktop version, it doesn't work. I have tried running the .exe as administrator but it doesn't work and I can't put a higher priority on the startups in windows. The script used to work in the old Skype version.

Maybe you guys help me out with some ideas or something else to try out to fix the problem.

This is the script that I have:

```
;------SPANISH ACCENTS
,-------------------------------------
; -Press Ctrl + Alt + Letter to replace with the accented version (including shift for capital letters)

^!a:: Send {Asc 160}   ; á
^!+a:: Send {Asc 0193} ; Á
^!e:: Send {Asc 130}   ; é
^!+e:: Send {Asc 144}  ; É
^!i:: Send {Asc 161}   ; í
^!+i:: Send {Asc 0205} ; Í
^!o:: Send {Asc 162}   ; Ó
^!+o:: Send {Asc 0211} ; Ó
^!u:: Send {Asc 163}   ; ú
^!+u:: Send {Asc 0218} ; Ú
^!n:: Send {Asc 164}   ; ñ
^!+n:: Send {Asc 165}  ; Ñ
^!':: Send {Asc 129}   ; ü
^!+':: Send {Asc 154}  ; Ü
^!/:: Send {Asc 168}   ; ¿
^!1:: Send {Asc 173}   ; ¡

;------SPOTIFY CONTROLS
,-------------------------------------
^!Left::Send   {Media_Prev}
^!Down::Send   {Media_Play_Pause}
^!Right::Send  {Media_Next}
+^!Left::Send  {Volume_Down}
+^!Down::Send  {Volume_Mute}
+^!Right::Send {Volume_Up}
```

Thanks in ahead.

Comment: Can you run other commands in your Skype program? E.g. `^F1::MsgBox F1 pressed`? (By the way, you can simply your script by just using `^!a::á`)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried today and yes, this `^F1::MsgBox F1 pressed` 
 command it works on Skype.
Btw thanks for the tip to simplify the script.